# Escape single quote querying recsel from fzf

Tags: bash, shell-script

I started to use GNU recutils for personal databases. In this case, it's about a books database. Also, I wish to use FZF to navigate between books, so I can search books by title and preview all the information.

The following script works well excepting when there's a single quote in the title:

```bsh
recsel -C books.rec -P "Title" | fzf --preview "recsel -e \"Title='\"{}\"'\" books.rec"
```

The following expression would work: `-e "Title='My best book'"`

The following one, wouldn't: `-e "Title='It's a nice book'"`

According to GNU Recutils documentation, the expression must be in the format `-e "Field='Value'"`, so I have no idea how to achieve this. The single quotes surrounding the Value are problem here. What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours reading and testing I could find the solution. It was clearly a syntax issue on my code and a mistake about the `recsel` syntax.

The format `-e 'Field="Value"'` also works (swiching single quotes to double quotes and viceversa). And expanding (to the left and to the right) the position of the single quotes also works when I use the command `fzf --preview`, so this is the result:

```bsh
recsel -C books.rec -P Title | fzf --preview 'recsel -e Title=\"{}\" books.rec'
```